# How to center an iframe in a div for maximum width using Tailwind?

Tags: next.js, iframe, tailwind-css

I am trying to align my embedded YouTube video using iFrame and increase it's width to the parent div. Only the next/Image worked but iFrame is not working.

[image]

I want my embedded YouTube look like the Image which aligned center, has similar width to parent div, responsive, and doesn't spill over when I change screen dimensions.

```
let projectDisplay = <Image src={project.filePath} alt="Project Stock Image" width="0" height="0" sizes="100vw" className="w-full h-auto" />; 

if (project.isVideo) {
    let youtubeStr = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + project.filePath;
    projectDisplay = <Iframe url={youtubeStr} 
        className='block relative w-full h-auto'
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowFullScreen />
}

<div className="border-black border-2 m-2 p-2 bg-blue-200 text-gray-900 flex-col">
    <div className='flex justify-center relative p-2 w-fit h-auto'>
        {projectDisplay}
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make my iFrame video look like the Image?